# htaccess redirecting not working from gmail link

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla2.5

I am having problem if I send one link by email. When people click on non-www link from gmail they redirect to home page of my site but when they click on www added link they reached in the correct page. Here is one example:

http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgreatratedjs.com%2Fcurtnw&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH_VlMDSssNnC-20Fliz9oT7Ip3ag (not working with non-www)

http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.greatratedjs.com%2Fcurtnw&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNE-ld9HPvMYZMLh-IVib7insdGRyQ (working fine with www)

My .htaccess redirecting rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am using Joomla with community builder. Joomla content are working fine only Community builder's user profile has such problem. I am using sh404sef extension for URL management. Any suggestion ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: seems to work both now, it depends how redirects from non-www are set up on your web server

Comment: Thanks for your comment jgod. But it's not working from me. non-www link redirecting to home page :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me as well. But in your rule, adding the `B` flag should ensure that weird characters from the `$1` capture get correctly re-encoded.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [B,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are those 2 link reaching in same page for you ? or the 1st one is home page & the 2nd one is Curt Hoagland page ? But both link should reach to Curt Hoagland page :) & it's not working from my firefox browser.. Is that working for you ?

Comment: In my browser they are both reaching the Curt page. Mmm, if that's your dev machine maybe it's just something with your setup, that's happened to me! lol =) Do you have another computer in the house?

Comment: Hi, I figure that out :) .. It's Joomla cache. I cleaned those & it's started working again :)

Answer (score 0):

It is important to use [`NE` (no escape) flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) here. Also better to use `REQUEST_URI`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

1. It is advisable to use `R=302` in your testing and once it is working fine change it to `R=301`.
2. Make sure to keep this rule as your very first rule in Joomla `.htaccess`.
3. Test in a new browser to avoid old caches in browser.